# How shall we write get method, so that private fields don't escape their intended scope?

Tags: java, multithreading

From Java Concurrency in Practice

> Publishing one object may indirectly publish others. If you add a
>   Secret to the published knownSecrets set, you’ve also published that
>   Secret, because any code can iterate the Set and obtain a reference to
>   the new Secret. Similarly, returning a reference from a nonprivate
>   method also publishes the returned object. UnsafeStates in Listing 3 .
>   6 publishes the supposedly private array of state abbreviations.
>
> ```
> class UnsafeStates {    
>     private String[] states = new String[] {        
>         "AK", "AL" ...        
>     };    
>     public String[] getStates() { return states; }    
> }
> ```
>
> Publishing states in this way is problematic because any caller can
>   modify its contents. In this case, the states array has escaped its
>   intended scope, because what was supposed to be private state has been
>   effectively made public.

In the example, what is the correct way to write `getStates` method, so that the states array doesn't escape its intended scope?

Is it correct that the quote about escape isn't directly related to multithreading and synchronization?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Java's Arrays and Collections.
to create a read only wrapper.

```
return Collections.unmodifiableList(Arrays.asList(states));
```

NOTE: don't worry about the Strings getting modified, they're immutable.

Comment: Thanks. Does the problem in my post only apply to reference types but not to value types?

Comment: Yes, just don't forget  arrays of primitive value types are reference types too.

Answer (score -2):

```
class SafeStates {

  private List<String> states;

  public List<String> getStates() {
    return states;
  }

  public void setStates(List<String> states) {
    this.states = Collections.unmodifiableList(states);
  }
}
```

Comment: This class is not trustworthy. Way too easy to manipulate the `states` without SafeStates being able to prevent that.

Comment: getStates()[0] = "evil"; modifies.

Comment: modification will not be possible: UnsupportedOperationException will be thrown

Comment: please read: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#unmodifiableList(java.util.List)

Comment: Have you read the linked Java Doc? Do you know what "view" means? That posted example thinks that no one will or can modify the list passed to `setStates`, which is obviously not true.

Comment: General idea is to hold unmodifiable list inside instance instead of creating it each time whenever getter is being called (which will obviously decrease performance). Setter could be replaced by any code which loads states into memory. It used here just for example because hardcoded valves is not good, and real use case of this code is unknown.

Comment: No one is talking about hardcoded values. Your code fails to cut the link between the passed list and the internal used one. Therefore the "immutability" is just a façade.